# Grid View pop up box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid view in an asp page. it has a read only field of quantity plus two update fields a quantity good and a quantity scrapped.  What I'm trying to do is have a pop up conformation which says are they sure they want to update the record.  Then if the UPDATED quantity good is greater than 120% of the quantity or the UPDATED quantity good plus the UPDATED quantity scrapped is 120% greater than the quantity it pops up a second conformation box.

I'm very new to all this, so please be gentle in your explanations.  I've got so far, but struggle to get the updated amount into the code behind (C#).

Many thanks

Matt

Here's a the grid view.

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="wona,wopnumber" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Horizontal" PageSize="20" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" >
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to update this ?');"></asp:LinkButton>
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Font-Size="x-Large"/>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Route Card" Text="Route Card"  DataNavigateUrlFields="wona,wopnumber" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/OpUpdate/RouteCard.aspx?wona={0}&wopnumber={1}" >
            <ItemStyle Font-Size="x-Large" />
            </asp:HyperLinkField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="wona" HeaderText="WO No" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="wona" >
            <ItemStyle Font-Size="Large" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="wopnumber" HeaderText="Op No" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="wopnumber" >
            <ItemStyle Font-Size="Medium" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="wqordered" HeaderText="Qty Ord" SortExpression="wqordered" ReadOnly="True" >
            <ItemStyle Font-Size="x-Large" Font-Bold="True" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="wqscrapped" HeaderText="Scrppd" SortExpression="wqscrapped" DataFormatString="{0:R}" >
            <ItemStyle Font-Size="x-Large" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="wqgood" HeaderText="Good" SortExpression="wqgood" DataFormatString="{0:R}" >
            <ItemStyle Font-Size="x-Large" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="partid" HeaderText="Part No" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http://webserver01.haigh.local:8084/CadDrawing/CadDrawing.aspx?partid={0}" DataTextField="partid" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="duedate" HeaderText="Due Date" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="duedate" >
            <ItemStyle Font-Size="x-Large" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="priority" HeaderText="Priority" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="priority">
            <ItemStyle Font-Size="x-Large" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="partdesc" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="partdesc" ReadOnly="True" >
            <ItemStyle Font-Size="Small" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="materialgroup" HeaderText="Mat Grp" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="materialgroup" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="opstatus" HeaderText="opstatus" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="opstatus" ItemStyle-CssClass="collapse"  >
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="collapse" />
            <ItemStyle CssClass="collapse"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:ImageField HeaderText="OP" ReadOnly="True" >
            </asp:ImageField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="kitstatus" HeaderText="kitstatus" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="kitstatus" ItemStyle-CssClass="collapse" >
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="collapse" />
            <ItemStyle CssClass="collapse"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:ImageField HeaderText="Kit" ReadOnly="True">
            </asp:ImageField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="matstatus" HeaderText="matstatus" SortExpression="matstatus" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-CssClass="collapse" >
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="collapse" />
            <ItemStyle CssClass="collapse"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:ImageField HeaderText="Mat" ReadOnly="True">
            </asp:ImageField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F4F4FD" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#5A4C9D" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D8D8F0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#3E3277" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

And the code behind

```
public partial class OpUpdate : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters["aduser"].DefaultValue = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
    }
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[12].Text == "Grn")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[13].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: url(../Images/Grn.png) no-repeat center;");

            }
            if (e.Row.Cells[12].Text == "Ambr")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[13].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: url(../Images/Ambr.png) no-repeat  center;");

            }
            if (e.Row.Cells[12].Text == "Red")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[13].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: url(../Images/Red.png) no-repeat  center;");

            }
            if (e.Row.Cells[14].Text == "Grn")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[15].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: url(../Images/Grn.png) no-repeat center;");

            }
            if (e.Row.Cells[14].Text == "Ambr")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[15].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: url(../Images/Ambr.png) no-repeat  center;");

            }
            if (e.Row.Cells[14].Text == "Red")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[15].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: url(../Images/Red.png) no-repeat  center;");

            }
            if (e.Row.Cells[16].Text == "Grn")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[17].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: url(../Images/Grn.png) no-repeat center;");

            }
            if (e.Row.Cells[16].Text == "Ambr")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[17].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: url(../Images/Ambr.png) no-repeat  center;");

            }
            if (e.Row.Cells[16].Text == "Red")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[17].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: url(../Images/Red.png) no-repeat  center;");

            }
            if (e.Row.Cells[16].Text == "Blu")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[17].Attributes.Add("Style", "background: url(../Images/Blu.png) no-repeat  center;");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, you need to include the code you've got so far. Not all of it, just the relevant bits.

Comment: Thanks Hugo, don't fall over laughing when you see it:-)